# How is it possible for a standing wave to exist in a tube with both sides open?

Tags: waves, acoustics, superposition

A standing wave is the result of the interference of 2 opposing waves right?
Then how can this diagram on the upper left be true?[image: harmonics of standing waves]

One sound wave is created by the musician, the other is supposed to come as a reflection, how?

And if the second, opposing wave is somehow generated by reflection, shouldn't the point where it was created be a node, not an anti node?

Comment: The atmosphere acts as a reflector.

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-5/Open-End-Air-Columns might be a help

Comment: [Acoustic Impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance) might also help.